# How to read an ORC file stored locally in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, data-science, orc

Can I think of an ORC file as similar to a CSV file with column headings and row labels containing data? If so, can I somehow read it into a simple pandas dataframe? I am not that familiar with tools like Hadoop or Spark, but is it necessary to understand them just to see the contents of a local ORC file in Python?

The filename is `someFile.snappy.orc`

I can see online that `spark.read.orc('someFile.snappy.orc')` works, but even after `import pyspark`, it is throwing error.

Answer (score 11):

I haven't been able to find any great options, there are a few dead projects trying to wrap the java reader. However, pyarrow does have an ORC reader that won't require you using pyspark. It's a bit limited but it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.orc as orc

with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    data = orc.ORCFile(file)
    df = data.read().to_pandas()
```

Comment: In my case I needed `with open(filename, 'rb') as file:` to avoid the decoding error `pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Arrow error: IOError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 11: invalid start byte`.

Comment: pyarrow works very well with Parquet but with ORC there seems to be some issues.

Comment: @Vic you should open the file with the 'rb' mode instead

Comment: why does pyarrow not have module orc? Has that changed? @Rafal Janik

Comment: Upon restarting a sagemaker instance, I also found the pyarrow._orc module to be missing.  It was working before.  
`ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-07bf84f8f5db> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install pyarrow')
----> 2 from pyarrow import  orc

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/orc.py in <module>()
     23 from pyarrow import types
     24 from pyarrow.lib import Schema
---> 25 import pyarrow._orc as _orc
     26 
     27 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow._orc'`

Answer (score 4):

In case `import pyarrow.orc as orc` does not work (did not work for me in Windows 10), you can read them to Spark data frame then convert to `pandas`'s data frame

```py
import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

findspark.init()
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df_spark = spark.read.orc('example.orc')
df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Pandas 1.0.0, there is a built in function for Pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_orc.html

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.orc 

df = pd.read_orc('/tmp/your_df.orc')
```

Be sure to read this warning about dependencies. This function might not work on Windows
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#install-warn-orc

> If you want to use
> read_orc(), it is highly recommended to install pyarrow using conda

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is using [pyorc](https://pyorc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
import pyorc
import pandas as pd

with open(r"my_orc_file.orc", "rb") as orc_file:
    reader = pyorc.Reader(orc_file)
    orc_data = reader.read()
    orc_schema = reader.schema

columns = list(orc_schema.fields)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=orc_data, columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

ORC, like AVRO and PARQUET, are format specifically designed for massive storage. You can think about them "like a csv", they are all files containing data, with their particular structure (different than csv, or a json of course!).

Using `pyspark` should be easy [reading an orc file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=orc#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.orc), as soon as your environment grants the Hive support.
Answering your question, I'm not sure that in a local environment without Hive you will be able to read it, I've never done it (you can do a quick test with the following code):

> Loads ORC files, returning the result as a DataFrame.
>
> Note: Currently ORC support is only available together with Hive support.
>
> >>> df = spark.read.orc('python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned')

Hive is a data warehouse system, that allows you to query your data on HDFS (distributed file system) through Map-Reduce like a traditional relational database (creating queries SQL-like, doesn't support 100% all the standard SQL features!).

**Edit**: Try the following to create a new Spark Session. Not to be rude, but  I suggest you to follow one of many PySpark tutorial in order to understand the basics of this "world". Everything will be much clearer.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()
```

Comment: My example works with Spark, please note that Pandas is a different library (even if they both have their own DataFrame implementation, this makes confusion I guess). Spark is designed to work in a distributed way, Pandas for analysis on a single PC.

Comment: Spark has some overhead as it needs to create a context (and pyspark is a large binary). I did this before, but do not recommend if other options are available.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to submit a spark job to read local ORC files or have pandas. This worked for me.

```
import pyarrow.orc as orc
data_reader = orc.ORCFile("/path/to/orc/part_file.zstd.orc")
data = data_reader.read()
source = data.to_pydict()
```